# How to limit access to a product to a group with time?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm new to Prestashop but perfectly able to modify the sources.

How could I limit access to a given product to only one given group 24 hours before the other groups ?

Thanks for answering this.

Answer (score 2):

By default Prestashop does not offer this feature. You can enable or disable access for the whole group which apply for all products.

You will need to write a module your self or buy a module which does this for you.

Searching the WWW i have found this module which is free (http://store.nemops.com/free-modules/44-product-access.html) however not compatible with 1.7. With some basic PHP knowledge you can easily upgrade the module to 1.7.

You can also find multiple paid modules which does this for you (https://addons.prestashop.com/en/search?search_query=product%20access)

Comment: Thanks but none of the modules are having the ability to limit access by date, I found a workaround by buying a module that is restricting access by password and this password is sent at the right date to every members of one group. After 24 hours the password is deleted for all the customers to gain access.